# hasManyThrough() use first "through" relationship only

Tags: laravel, eloquent, relationship, eager-loading

I am currently struggling with the hasManyThrough() function. Basically, I'm trying to eager load an n to n relationship, but I only want to include the first "through" relationship. Here's an example:

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Project extends Model
{
    /**
     * Get all of the deployments for the project.
     */
    public function deployments()
    {
        return $this->hasManyThrough(Deployment::class, Environment::class);
    }
```

```
project:
   id: 1
   name: Project1

environment:
   id: 1
   project_id: 1
   name: environment1

   id: 2
   project_id: 1
   name: environment2

deployment:
   id: 1
   environment_id: 1
   commit_hash: xxxx1

   id: 2
   environment_id: 1
   commit_hash: xxx11

   id: 3
   environment_id: 2
   commit_hash: xxxx2
```

The `deployments()` function here obviously returns all the `deployments` for all `environments` of a specific `project`. How would I be able to **only fetch the `deployments` of the first** (or last) `environments` entry of a `projects` entry? In this case, this would be the `environment` with `id: 1` and deployments with `id: 1` and `id: 2`, for example.

Comment: `$project->environments()->first()->deployments`, or `$project->environments()->latest()->first()->deployments`. As long as you define a relationship for Project -> Environments, and Environment -> Deployments, then you can chain them like that. `hasManyThrough()` is meant as a quick shortcut for this kind of thing.

Comment: @TimLewis Does this also work with eager loading, like in my case? I currently have this weird behaviour, that using `$this->environments()->first()->deployments()` uses the project ID to fetch the deployments instead of the environment ID.

Comment: Hmm, not exactly. You'd have to define the relationship for `environment` (like the answer below), then `$project = Project::with(['environment.deployments'])->first()`, would allow you to call `$project->environment->deployments`. Also, you have to do `->deployments` or `->deployments()->get()`. `->deployments()` is a Builder instance, needs a Closure (`->get()`, `->first()`, `->paginate()`, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

I think you may want to specify a hasOne relationship like so:

```php
// Project.php
public function environment()
{
    return $this->hasOne(Environment::class);
}
```

And then you could eager-load the deployments using:

```php
Project::with(['environment.deployments'])
```

I don't think you will be able to build a `developments()` relationship function on Project but someone might prove me wrong.